# Escaping double quotes for JS within Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am using GoJS library for drawing a graph. I am trying to display the following JavaScript code on the page (that's what I need to see as the page source when it's finished loading):

```
myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel([
    { key: "Node26", color: "lightgreen"},
    { key: "Node25", color: "lightgreen"},
    { key: "Node33", color: "lightgreen"},
    { key: "Node42", color: "lightgreen"}],
 [
    { from: "Node26, to: "Node25"},
    { from: "Node26, to: "Node33"},
    { from: "Node33, to: "Node42"},
    { from: "Node33, to: "Node41"},
    { from: "Node33, to: "Node57"},
    { from: "Node33, to: "Node25"},
    { from: "Node33, to: "Node34"}
]);
```

This code is generated on the server using razor syntax like this:

```
@{
    string nodes = "";
    string links = "";
    string childName;

    foreach (Node node in Model.FullGraph)
    {
        nodes += "{ key: \"" + node.NodeName + "\"},";
        @foreach (uint childId in node.ChildrenIds)
        {
            childName = Model.FullGraph.Find(x => x.NodeId == childId).NodeName;
            links += "{ from: \"" + node.NodeName + "\", to: \"" + childName + "\"},";

        }
    }
}
    myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel([@nodes], [@links]);
```

However, after loading the resulting page looks like this in HTML:

```
myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel([
    { key: &quot;Node26&quot;, color: &quot;lightgreen&quot;},
    { key: &quot;Node25&quot;, color: &quot;lightgreen&quot;},
    { key: &quot;Node33&quot;, color: &quot;lightgreen&quot;},
    { key: &quot;Node42&quot;, color: &quot;lightgreen&quot;}],
 [
    { from: &quot;Node26, to: &quot;Node25&quot;},
    { from: &quot;Node26, to: &quot;Node33&quot;},
    { from: &quot;Node33, to: &quot;Node42&quot;},
    { from: &quot;Node33, to: &quot;Node41&quot;},
    { from: &quot;Node33, to: &quot;Node57&quot;},
    { from: &quot;Node33, to: &quot;Node25&quot;},
    { from: &quot;Node33, to: &quot;Node34&quot;}
]);
```

Escaping with backslash doesn't work, the code still replaces double quotes with " and therefore the graph is not drawn. When I manually replace them back to normal double quotes using developer tools in the browser, the graph is drawn.

I've also tried using `@` for escaping, and `Html.Raw()` as well. Nothing works. Does anyone have some suggestions? Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: It's not really a fix, more a work around. Replace all quotation marks with apostrophes in the javascript... they both worth the same and so it should be fine.

Comment: You don't have to create object literals by manually placing quotes. Use `var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.YourList))` to conver the list to an array. Then create those 2 arrays in javascript

Comment: Also, where is `color` in your loop?

Comment: Thank you a lot! Apostrophe hack worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my curiosity I have tried different options as well in the meantime, let me share the iterations what I have tested.

I have built a small class for testing:

```
public class ColoredObject
{
    public string key { get; set; }

    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

For testing purposes created a list where adding 2 test objects:

```
var list = new List<ColoredObject>()
{
    new ColoredObject()
    {
        key = "Node26",
        color = "lightgreen"
    },
    new ColoredObject()
    {
        key = "Node25",
        color = "lightgreen"
    }
};
```

**Apostrophe version:**
Then creating the JSON object in Razor:

```
string nodesWithApostrophe = "[";

foreach (var i in list)
{
    nodesWithApostrophe += "{ key: '" + i.key + "', color: '" + i.color + "'},";
}

nodesWithApostrophe += "]";
```

So the first solution which is working fine and logging to the console properly the created array as expected is the following:

```
let jsonObject = @Html.Raw(nodesWithApostrophe);
console.log('testJson with apostrophe', jsonObject);
```

[image: JSON with apostrophe]

**Double quotes version:**
I was interested how to create object with double quotes also, so I have changed to escape chars in foreach:

```
string nodesWithDQ = "[";

foreach (var i in list)
{
    nodesWithDQ += "{ key: \"" + i.key + "\", color: \"" + i.color + "\"},";
}

nodesWithDQ += "]";
```

Also doing the same in JavaScript made it work:

```
let jsonObject = @Html.Raw(nodesWithDQ);
console.log('testJson with double quotes', jsonObject);
```

[image: With double quotes]